# Assigning list of HashMap to another list of HashMap as method return value

Tags: arraylist, methods, hashmap, return, assign

I am trying to assign a method's return value to a List of HashMaps.

**Method returning List**

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getDetails() {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> info = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> components = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        //Fetched some result from DataBase in ResultSet (assume i have fetched three rows).
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            components.put("id", rs.getString("id"));
            components.put("columnA", rs.getString("columnA"));                         
            components.put("columnB", rs.getString("columnB"));
            components.put("columnC", rs.getString("columnC"));
            components.put("columnD", rs.getString("columnD"));
            info.add(components);
        }
        return info;
}
```

**Calling Method**

```
public void dispDetails(){

        List<HashMap<String, String>> info = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        details = getDetails();
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.println(details.get(i).get("id"));
        System.out.println(details.get(i).get("columnA"));
        System.out.println(details.get(i).get("columnB"));
        System.out.println(details.get(i).get("columnC"));
        System.out.println(details.get(i).get("columnD"));

        }


}
```

But somehow all the values in the calling methods list(i.e dispDetails) are same.

Is there any way to assign the list.

Comment: "... add some values". You know you have cut out the most important part of your code?

Comment: Can you post assertDetails code